# How can I connect a socket to the server?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to create a socket in a client.js file to communicate with my server. I followed the official documentation ( https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express ) with no success. Basically when I initialize my socket like this:

```
var socket = io();
```

i expect a message from my server (e.g. 'A user has connected') but nothing appear, letting me suppose that the connection never happens.

This is a project made on Glitch. I tried to follow socket.io documentation, simple examples or other questions tips. I both tried the suggested script before instantiate the socket and the cdn one.

//server.js

```
//dependencies
const express = require('express');
const app     = express();
const http    = require('http').Server(app);
const io      = require('socket.io')(http);  

//listening to the port
http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port " + process.env.PORT);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('A user has connected.');
});
```

//chat.html

```
//this is called right before </body>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js'></script>
<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
<script src='/public/client.js'></script>
```

//client.js

```
var socket = io();
```

client.js is loaded as expected (and the console throws no errors) but i can't see 'A user has connected' as i'd expect.

You can check full source code here https://glitch.com/edit/#!/farlokko-advanced-node

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

The problem was a wrong initialization of the passport.socketio module, which interfered with sicket.io . The main problem probably was a wrong store(memoryStore instead of mongo-store) and a wrong key for the cookie (express.sid instead of connect.sid).

Finally socket initialization was ok and had to be io.connect("host here").

Answer (score 0):

As specified on the [doc](https://socket.io/docs/#Using-with-Express), you have to configure the client to connect to your localhost, and then, on the connection, you'll have your message :

```
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');  // <--- HERE MAN
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that...maybe i'm passing the wrong string inside my connect function; i tried with ' http://127.0.0.1 ' but i'm not sure that's correct. I also tried with the glitch project url itself. What should i write there in my specific case? :)